# Import org.apache cannot be resolved

Tags: java, jar, apache-poi

I've follow at least 5 websites tutorials on adding the jar file for apache, but it still gives me the same error. Am I missing something?

[image: Shows the error]
[image: Jar file loaded for apache, but its not working]

Comment: Tried the quickfixes already ?

Comment: Check your first screenshot

Comment: To remove the imports? No i don't want to do that.

Comment: Well open the JAR and check if it acually contains those packages orga/pache/poi/hwpf in particular. It does also help to delete all error markgers in the "problem" view or to use Project->clean and rebuild the project.

Comment: Just downloaded it to check.  The .jar file you are using doesn't contain the classes you're trying to import.  You need some other jar.

Answer (score 3):

The jar file which you need to add to the build path is "poi-scratchpad-3.13-20150929.jar" which has the classes you are looking for.

Comment: You might want to add a reference to [the place on the Apache POI website which explains what's in which jar](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components)